# Array to pointers not initializing

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, initialization, valgrind

I am trying to initialize an array of pointers to a struct TLDNode. I do this by traversing a tree and adding the nodes in-order to it. However, I'm using valgrind's memcheck tool, and it has pointed out:

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
    at 0x400D55: main (tldmonitor.c:88)
  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
    at 0x4C28C0F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
    by 0x4014CA: tldlist_iter_create (tldlist.c:146)
    by 0x400CC8: main (tldmonitor.c:83)
```

I'm confused because I am initializing, even though it is in a different function.

Code:
tldlist.c

```
static void inorder_add(TLDIterator *iter, TLDNode *c) {
    if(c != NULL) {
        inorder_add(iter,c->left);
        *(iter->array + iter->index) = c;//intialize each index
        iter->index++;
        inorder_add(iter,c->right);
    }
}

TLDIterator* tldlist_iter_create(TLDList *tld) {
    TLDIterator *iter = malloc(sizeof(TLDIterator));
    if(iter != NULL) {
        iter->length = tldlist_count(tld);
        iter->index = 0;
        iter->array = malloc(sizeof(TLDNode*)*iter->length);//line 146
        inorder_add(iter,tld->root);
        iter->index = 0;
        return iter;
    }
    return NULL;
}

TLDNode* tldlist_iter_next(TLDIterator* iter) {
    if(iter->index < iter->length) {
        TLDNode *next = *(iter->array+iter->index);
        iter->index++;
        return next;
    }   
    return NULL;
}
```

tldmonitor.c:

```
tld = tldlist_create(begin, end);
//nodes are added in between
total = (double)tldlist_count(tld);
it = tldlist_iter_create(tld); //line 83
while ((n = tldlist_iter_next(it))) {//line 88 (84-87 not needed)
        printf("%6.2f %s\n", 100.0 * (double)tldnode_count(n)/total, tldnode_tldname(n));
    }
```

tldmonitor is supposed to print out the percentage of each key's count in the tree. However, tldmonitor.c was given as starter code, so my issue must be in tldlist.c.

Why is it saying I am not initializing? Is it because I do it in a separate function? Or am I actually not initializing the array in some way?

Comment: `*(iter->array+iter->index);`. valgrind seems to be telling you that at least some of the contents of `iter->array` is not initialised.

Comment: Where is the content of `iter->array` actually initialized *after* allocation? That `malloc` was used to get the block referenced by `iter->array`, but at least *some* of the memory content of said-same block is indeterminate, thus the complaint.

Comment: @kaylum and @WhozCraig, I intend for all of `iter->array` to be initialized in inorder_add(), at `*(iter->array + iter->index) = c;`. Is there an error there?

Comment: We can't tell because we don't know what `tld->root` is and what the tree looks like that it is pointing to. But it looks to me that each branch of the recusrion stops when either `left` or `right` is NULL. That is, it  does not initialise the elements in the `array` that correspond to NULL nodes in `tld->root`. Fix by using `calloc` for the `array` allocation or explicitly NULL out after allocation.